# Creating html content with SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, templates, generate

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I can use it in another version.

I have variables of an html page content in my tables.

SQL Server tables:

```
PageVariables
Menus
Slides etc.
```

Can I generate page html in SQL Server without programming?

I tried to do it with Replace partially. But it doesn't work on multi-line tables. I don't think this is the right way either.

Is there something like SQL Server in javascript like mustache, vue, javascript literal?

```html
declare @template nvarchar(max)='<html><head>{title}</title></head><body><div class="menu">{menu}</div></body></html>'

declare @title  nvarchar(max)='My Page'
declare @menu  nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT 'My Menu-1' AS 'MenuName',
       '?link=1' AS 'MenuLink'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'My Menu-2' AS 'MenuName',
       '?link=2' AS 'MenuLink'

/*
for @menu
    set @menu='<a href="@MenuLink">@MenuName</a>'
next
*/
SET @template = REPLACE(@template, '{title}', @title)
SET @template = REPLACE(@template, '{menu}', @menu)

SELECT @template
```

it is also difficult in this way.

```html
        SELECT '?link=1' AS '@href',
               'My Menu-1' AS 'span'

        UNION ALL
        SELECT '?link=2' AS '@href',
               'My Menu-2' AS 'span'

        FOR XML PATH ('a'), ROOT ('div')
```

Comment: As a general rule, SQL is not meant to produce user interfaces. It's meant for storing and retrieving data to/from a database. You can perform some level of rendering, but you'll soon find it's not meant for it. You'll need an app layer, albeit simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is one of these [string concatenation operations](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string) when you have multiple rows that you need to combine into single entry:

1. Concatenate Multiple Rows Using FOR XML PATH
2. Concatenate Rows Using COALESCE
3. Using STRING_AGG

Answer (score 1):

It is doable, but The Impaler is correct, you may outgrow this technique quickly.

The map table can have as many items as needed.  Even items not needed, they will be ignored.

**Here is a simplified example.**

```
declare @template nvarchar(max)='
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="welcome">{username}</div>
        <div class="menu">
            {menu}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
'

Declare @map table (Seq int,Item varchar(100),Value varchar(max))
Insert Into @map values
 (1   ,'{title}','My Page')
,(2   ,'{username}','Mary-Jane')
,(9999,'{title}','')             -- clean-up
,(9999,'{username}','')          -- clean-up
,(9999,'{menu}','')              -- clean-up


-- Generate from select ... note the trailing {menu}
Insert Into @map values  
 (1  ,'{menu}','<a href="My Menu-1">?link=1</a>{menu}')
,(2  ,'{menu}','<a href="My Menu-2">?link=2</a>{menu}')



Select @template=replace(@template,Item,Value)
 From  @map
 Order By Seq

Print @template
```

**Returns**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="welcome">Mary-Jane</div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="My Menu-1">?link=1</a><a href="My Menu-2">?link=2</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice and shows how he could build the tables to make his web site data-driven rather than generating the HTML in SQL.  Also, beats trying to COALESCE, etc all the rows and strings together.

Comment: @Pete-S- Very kind.  You're right, I use tables, but also some fun items which dynamically unpivots a record (not dynamic sql), for items like FName,LName,EMail, Date Strings, etc.